# 8-neighboorhood in vector from nonZeroCoordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

From an edge image 8UC1 obtained from Canny operator, I want to go through all white pixels and find their 8-neighboorhood.

As a first step, I apply

```
findNonZero(edgesFromCanny, nonZeroCoordinates);
```

to obtain just all white pixels to increase computational time. 
The coordinates of those pixels in *nonZeroCoordinates* are then ordered in a row-wise manner, so that p(x=100, y =1) can be far away from p(x=100, y=2) in the *nonZeroCoordinates* Mat (column-wise), while p(x=100, y =1) and p(x=101, y =1) are subsequent in *nonZeroCoordinates* (if they are edges).

How can I (fast) retrieve the 8-neighboorhood of p(x=100, y=1) taking into account, it is an edge, too?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all white pixels in the 8-neighboorhood? Because without any extra condition the 8-neighboorhood is simply the 8 pixels around each white pixel.

Comment: Yes, I just want to retrieve all those white pixels, that are located in the 8-neighboorhood of the actual pixel (pixel i,j and +1/-1 around i,j) - this means, that black pixels in this particular neighboor should not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using kNN, but I am not sure if this solution does not take too much computation or there can be a simpler one:

```
    vector<Point2f> edgesVec; //Insert all 2D points to this vector
    flann::KDTreeIndexParams indexParams;
    flann::Index kdtree(Mat(edgesVec).reshape(1), indexParams);
    vector<float> query;
    query.push_back(i); //Insert the 2D point we need to find neighbours to the query
    query.push_back(j); //Insert the 2D point we need to find neighbours to the query
    vector<int> indices;
    vector<float> dists;
    kdtree.radiusSearch(query, indices, dists, 1.5, 8);
```